Where can I find all channels from the photohadronic interaction $p + \gamma\rightarrow$ ...?
I would like to know all possible channels of the photohadronic interaction: $$p + \gamma\rightarrow a + b + c \dots $$
For example: $$p + \gamma \rightarrow\Delta^+\rightarrow\pi^0 + p.$$ Do you know where I could find this information? Maybe a book, or paper, or internet resource? I can find some references on particular channels, but I need to know a list all possible secondaries. For instance, is it possible to have a direct channel to $\pi^0$ + p without the $\Delta$ resonance?

Perhaps try the PDG?

Specifically, the bottom of this, and, in particular, this and references therein. Just go to the voluminous printed version, if you wished to nurture your sanity.

I am not sure you can find "all of them" anywhere... there should be an infinite number of those, but the PDG should contain many if not all of the measured ones.

As a recovering photo disintegrator, I really prefer a leading gamma: $\gamma + p \rightarrow p +  \pi^0$, and if you're detecting the scattered proton from a gamma beam on an LH$_2$ target: $\gamma(p, \pi^0)p$ ..irrc.

Regarding the final question: Yes.
Here is a figure from The Web showing various photo-production cross sections:

which shows that resonant production is sitting on a smooth non-resonant background (so for a given event, you can't know if you made a delta or not, it's more likely that you did when on the resonance).
Now that shows versus incident photon energy.
Another plot I found shows vs $\sqrt s$, which I like more:

and my favorite is versus the invariant mass of the final state:

